# dimension codimension problem for a perturbation operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

> Let $H$ be a separable Hilbert space and let $L:H\to H$ be a compact
> self-adjoint bounded linear operator . Let $\lambda_0$ be a simple
> characteristic value and let $\phi_0$ be an eigenvector such that
> $\lambda_0L\phi_0=\phi_0$ and $\langle L\phi_0,\phi_0\rangle=1$ .
>
> Let $A:H\to H$ be a compact map such that $A(0)=0$ and the following
> property holds : There exists a constant $C>0$ if $||u||\leq r$ and
> $||v||\leq r$ for $u,v\in H$ , we have $||A(u)-A(v)||\leq Cr^2||u-v||$
> .
>
> Define a map $f:H\times\mathbb{R}\to H$ by $f(u,\lambda)=u-\lambda Lu+A(u)$
> for all $(u,\lambda)\in H\times\mathbb{R}$ . We can assume $f$ is $C^p$ for some $p\geq2$ .

**Now I want to show two things** :

$(1)$ $\ker(\partial_uf(0,\lambda_0))$ is a one-dimensional subspace of $H$ .

$(2)$ $\text{range}(\partial_uf(0,\lambda_0))$ has codimension $1$ .

**What I tried so far** :

$(1)$ It's not hard to see $\partial_uf(0,\lambda_0)=I-\lambda_0L+A$ and hence $$\partial_uf(0,\lambda_0)\phi_0=\phi_0-\lambda_0L\phi_0+A\phi_0=A\phi_0$$ but I am getting nowhere to show that $\text{span}\{\phi_0\}=\ker(\partial_uf(0,\lambda_0))$ .

$(2)$ It is enough to show there exists some $h^*\in H^*\setminus\{0\}$ such that $\ker(h^*)=\text{range}(\partial_uf(0,\lambda_0))$ , i.e. we need to find such $h^*$ so that $$h^*(u-\lambda_0Lu+A(u))=0 \ \ \ \text{for all} \ \ u\in H$$ But I am unable to find such $h^*$ .

I want to verify the approach of solutions I am trying to make . If my approach is misleading , then any alternative method of approach would be appreciated . Regards .

**Edit** : I attached screenshots related to the problem .

[image]

...............................................................................................................................................................

[image]

Of course , I wanted to check hypothesis $(ii),(iii)$ of theorem $4.3.3$ as : "**It is trivial to check that all the hypothesis of theorem 4.3.3. are verified...**" .

Comment: I am not confident enough in my mathematical abilities to say that your reference is wrong. However, I thought a long time about your problem and could not spot any assumption that would stop my counter example from working. My example suffices all properties given in your second reference and clearly, it fails the assertions of Theorem 4.3.3. So maybe you just encountered an error in the existing literature (what is by far not unheard of).

Comment: I also wrote an edit to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think your post missed out on some motivation. Probably, you tried to isolate the problem (for example, there is no motivation of the constants $C$ and $r$ and you also do not explain why we can assume that $f$ is in $C^p$) but the assumptions you present here are not sufficient. Maybe try to post the full problem.

> It's not hard to see $\partial_uf(0,\lambda_0)=I-\lambda_0L+A$ ...

This is actually wrong. Since $A$ is generally not linear, $\partial_uf(0,\lambda_0)$ is generally not a linear operator are therefore not the derivative on $f$ with respect to $u$. One rather has $$\partial_uf(0,\lambda_0) = I - \lambda_0 L + DA(0),$$ where $DA(0) \colon H \to H$ is the Fréchet derivative of $H$ which is by definition linear.

However, there is a counter example to the statements you try to prove even in finite dimensions. Indeed, consider the separable Hilbert space $H = \mathbb R^2$ and the linear operator $L \colon H \to H$ given by the matrix
$$ L := \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2\end{pmatrix}.$$
Then $L$ is compact since $H$ is finite-dimensional and self-adjoint since its eigenvalues $1$ and $2$ are real (actually it is even positive in the Hilbert-space sense and also positive in the sense of Banach lattices). Moreover, both eigenvalues $1$ and $2$ are simple, i.e., their respective eigenspaces are one-dimensional.

Moreover, set $A(x) := Lx$ for all $x \in H$. Then $A(0) = 0$ and $A$ satisfies the growth condition since
\begin{align*}
\lVert A(x) - A(y) \rVert_2^2 &= \lvert x_1 - y_1 \rvert^2 + 4 \lvert x_2 - y_2 \rvert^2 \\
&\leq 4 (\lvert x_1 - y_1 \rvert^2 + \lvert x_2 - y_2 \rvert^2) = 4 \lVert x - y\rVert_2^2
\end{align*}
for all $x, \, y \in H$. Just pick $C = 2$ and $r = 1$ e.g. but actually the growth condition we showed above is stronger than yours since our estimation does not depend on any $r$ whatsoever.

Moreover, $A$ is a compact map, i.e., if $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ is bounded in $H$, then $(A(x_n))_{n \in \mathbb N}$ has a convergent subsequence. Namely, $(A(x_n))_{n \in \mathbb N}$ is bounded if $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ is bounded due to the growth condition. Since $H$ is finite-dimensional, the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem then implies that $(A(x_n))_{n \in \mathbb N}$ has a convergent subsequence. Note that this argument works for all functions $A : H \to H$ satisfying the growth condition.

Now let's come to your two assertions: Clearly, we have $DA(0) = L$ and thus $$\partial_uf(0, 1) = I - \lambda_0 L + DA(0) = I$$, where $\lambda_0 = 1$. Therefore,
\begin{align*}
\ker \partial_uf(0, 1) & = \ker I = \{0\}, \\
\operatorname{codim}\partial_uf(0, 1) H &= \dim(H/\partial_uf(0, 1) H) = \dim (H/H) = \{0\}
\end{align*}
which shows that neither $\ker \partial_uf(0, 1)$ nor $\operatorname{codim}\partial_uf(0, 1) H$ is one-dimensional. However, I would really like to see the full problem!

**EDIT:** I just want to point out two things about Theorem 4.3.3 that really irritate me. I stress that this might just be a result of me being part of a different mathematical community.

However, eigenvalues are usually defined to be $\lambda \in \mathbb C$ such that $L \psi_0 = \lambda \psi_0$ and usually one considers eigenvectors that are normalized, i.e., $\langle \psi_0, \psi_0 \rangle = 1$, and not such that $\langle L\psi_0, \psi_0 \rangle = 1$.

Moreover, it is bad style to assume that $f$ is in $\mathcal C^p$ instead of assuming that $A$ is in $\mathcal C^p$. That would imply the former statement but yielding a weaker theorem. Maybe I am just not aware of the applications but I would bet that you would usally check that $f$ is in $\mathcal C^p$ by proving that $A$ is in $\mathcal C^p$. Surely, if you have some kind of cancelations going on you do not need that $A$ is in $\mathcal C^p$. However, I highly doubt that you can expect that from non-toy examples.

I would like to suggest that maybe your reference is flawed. That would not be unusual. If someone else can spot a flawed argument in my post I would be glad to know.

Comment: OK . I attached the source for the reference to the problem .